# Generating kubernetes client code with reference to existing kubernetes type

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I am playing around with writing a CRD for kubernetes, and am having trouble getting the code-generator to work. In particular, generating deepcopy functions is failing for a particular struct, which has reference to a `batch.JobTemplateSpec`. Commenting out that line fixes my issue.

I've already tried various imports and registering the `JobTemplateSpec` in `register.go`, but that doesn't seem to be the solution.

In particular, the struct looks something like this:

```golang
type TestSpec struct {

    Selector *metav1.LabelSelector `json:"selector,omitempty"`

    //Commenting out the JobTemplate fixes my problem
    JobTemplate batch.JobTemplateSpec `json:"jobTemplate,omitempty"`

}
```

What I end up getting is this error from the codegen script:

```
Generating client codes...
Generating deepcopy funcs
F0411 18:54:09.409084     251 deepcopy.go:885] Hit an unsupported type invalid type for invalid type, from test/pkg/apis/test/v1.TestSpec
```

and the rest of code gen fails.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue trying to replicate the steps in https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-deep-dive-code-generation-customresources/ and found that I needed to change directory to avoid this issue.

If I was at the root of my Go workspace, e.g. `$GOPATH/src`, I got the error you received. But if I changed to the project directory, e.g. `$GOPATH/src/github.com/openshift-evangelist/crd-code-generation`, the issue went away.